# expo build failed with exception Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew"

Tags: expo, eas

i'm trying to build my expo project to android using `eas build -p android`, but i keep getting this error:

```
[RUN_GRADLEW] FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[RUN_GRADLEW] 1: Task failed with an exception.
[RUN_GRADLEW] -----------
[RUN_GRADLEW] * Where:
[RUN_GRADLEW] Script '/tmp/curtis/eas-build-local-nodejs/3263ad7d-6f3a-4eab-87d0-78b49892e522/build/node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking/scripts/android/autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 272
[RUN_GRADLEW] * What went wrong:
[RUN_GRADLEW] A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
[RUN_GRADLEW] > A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-modules-core'.
[RUN_GRADLEW]    > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
[RUN_GRADLEW]       > SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/tmp/curtis/eas-build-local-nodejs/3263ad7d-6f3a-4eab-87d0-78b49892e522/build/android/local.properties'.
[RUN_GRADLEW]       > Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.
[RUN_GRADLEW] * Try:
[RUN_GRADLEW] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[RUN_GRADLEW] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[RUN_GRADLEW] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[RUN_GRADLEW] ==============================================================================
    [RUN_GRADLEW] 2: Task failed with an exception.
    [RUN_GRADLEW] -----------
    [RUN_GRADLEW] * What went wrong:
    [RUN_GRADLEW] A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
    [RUN_GRADLEW] > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
    [RUN_GRADLEW] * Try:
    [RUN_GRADLEW] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    [RUN_GRADLEW] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    [RUN_GRADLEW] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    [RUN_GRADLEW] ==============================================================================
    [RUN_GRADLEW] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    [RUN_GRADLEW] BUILD FAILED in 8m 47s
```

my app.json is this:

{
"expo": {
"name": "APP_NAME",
"slug": "APP_SLUG",
"version": "1.2.3",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/icon.png",
"userInterfaceStyle": "light",
"splash": {
"image": "./assets/splash.png",
"resizeMode": "contain",
"backgroundColor": "#000000"
},
"updates": {
"fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
},
"assetBundlePatterns": [
"**/*"
],
"ios": {
"supportsTablet": true
},
"android": {
"adaptiveIcon": {
"foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
"backgroundColor": "#000000"
},
"package": "com.APP_NAME.app",
"versionCode": 10
},
"web": {
"favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
},
"extra": {
"eas": {
"projectId": "PROJECT_ID"
}
},
"plugins": [
[
"expo-build-properties",
{
"android": {
"compileSdkVersion": 31,
"targetSdkVersion": 31,
"buildToolsVersion": "31.0.0"
},
"ios": {
"deploymentTarget": "13.0"
}
}
],
[
"expo-image-picker",
{
"photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let Upload Profile Pictures"
}
],
[
"expo-local-authentication",
{
"faceIDPermission": "Allow to use Face ID."
}
],
"expo-build-properties"
]
}
}

i even tried installing wsl and using eas build --local to try it locally but i still get the same issue, please how can i sole this?